# Optimizing number of blocks to maximal number of resident blocks on GPU

Tags: cuda

Is it possible to determine the number of maximal resident blocks on the whole GPU to avoid necessity of repetitive kernel execution as global barrier?

More exactly I want to avoid cost of copying partial results into the global memory and cost of kernel execution. So work will be fairly distributed to each block and blocks will fairly alternate their computations until one of them find result.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=60268) thread might be of use to you. In general, if the task is completely parallel, you don't have launch new kernels for the remainder of the data. Instead, you can just loop inside the kernel.

Comment: Thank you, I found [occupancy calculator](http://www.google.si/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=occupancy%20calculator&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.download.nvidia.com%2Fcompute%2Fcuda%2FCUDA_Occupancy_calculator.xls&ei=XQ4aT5iKE4qf-QbZg-ydCg&usg=AFQjCNG_VhxwvgVBBUZnnincdbTyvYLrKQ) very useful tool to see the real occupancy of GPU and to determine ideal size of blocks and used shared memory.